# When wouldn't you use -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries?

Tags: actionscript

Is there a reason you would not set `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries` to true when compiling an Actionscript project using `mxmlc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several applications for one project making the framework available as an RSL enables the other applications to load it from cache (it has been loaded there by the first app) and save bandwidth and time. If you set static linking to true, every application will contain the framework classes increasing your file sizes.

If you have only one application .swf, linking framework as an RSL can save bandwidth on updates - if only the main .swf changes, you can load it again bypassing the cache but load all the cached .swcs.

Comment: Is it then possible to include source files, say `FlashPunk` or `Flixel` without RSL— which I assume is `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries`? How?

Comment: sure, if you set static linking to true, the libs are included within the application, increasing the size.

Comment: So to be straight, otherwise you'd have to have them sourced or something?